# Switch to the node2vec method a bpmn file

Tags: python

I need to do the following:

- create a random walk through `node2vec`
- create paths with the PLG2 software
- save them in bpmn format.

**My problem**
After importing those paths on `pycharm` I don't know how to pass the graph in `bpmn` to `node2vec`.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

```
 ``
(python
import networkx as nx
from node2vec import Node2Vec
import gensim
import word2vec
# Create a graph
graph ='P1.bpmn'
# Precompute probabilities and generate walks - **ON WINDOWS ONLY WORKS WITH workers=1**
node2vec = Node2Vec(graph, dimensions=64, walk_length=3, num_walks=2, workers=1)  # Use temp_folder for big graphs

# Embed nodes
model = node2vec.fit(window=10, min_count=1, batch_words=4)  # Any keywords acceptable by gensim.Word2Vec can be passed, `diemnsions` and `workers` are automatically passed (from the Node2Vec constructor)


# Save embeddings for later use
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('Random_Walk')

# Save model for later use
model.save('Random_MODEL_Walk') )
 ``
```

Comment: Hi Erika, thank you and welcome to SO, Can you please provide a more detail Python code example of what you tried so far to improve the quality of your question, Use [This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55591825/edit) to edit your question

Comment: Hi, sorry I just added the link with the image of the code

Comment: Np, Can you simply paste your code into the question use [This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55591825/edit) to edit. Note: You have nice guidelines how to format the code to make it clear for example ```python your code ```

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot pass a string (`'P1.bpmn'`) into the `Node2Vec` constructor. It accepts a `networkx` graph. You should create a [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) graph first, and only then use the `Node2Vec` constructor

Comment: ok thanks, but can I build a network with networkx starting from the bpmn diagram?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bpmn diagram, you can check the `networkx` docs [https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.3/] for examples of how to build a `networkx` graph

Comment: if I save the network in the .dot format, I can switch from this to a networkx?

Comment: I really don't know, as I said, network X has a `networkx.Graph` module, that is the input that `Node2Vec` expects. Look for tutorials on how to take your specific formats and make them `networkx.Graph`s